# Calculating an area.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, definite-integrals, area

Compute the area between the parabolas $y=x^2$ , $y=\frac{x^2}{2}$ and the straight line $y =2x$.

I know the area is equal to $\int_{0}^2x^2-\frac{x^2}{2}+\int_{2}^42x-\frac{x^2}{2}$.

However I can't get this result unless I graph all the functions.

How do you calculate the area without having to graph the functions ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you made an image?

Comment: Isn't making an image the same as graphing the function ?

Comment: By all means graph the functions.  You don't need to be exact, but having a picture of your region is enormously helpful.  Then you can set the equations equal to one another to find the points of intersection.  i.e. $y=2x$ intersects $y = \frac 12 x^2 \implies 2x = \frac 12 x^2$

Comment: I think that what OP wants is a formal proof that the region is what one can "see". A proof that can be understood by a born blind mathematician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only common point of the parabolas is $(0,0)$, and this point is also in the line. Moreover, $x^2/2<x^2$ for $x>0$.

The line intersects the parabola $x^2$ in $(2,4)$ and the parabola $x^2/2$ in $(4,8)$. Moreover, $2x>x^2$ if $x\in(0,2)$ and $2x\le x^2$ otherwise. Also, $2x>x^2/2$ if $x\in(0,4)$ and $2x\le x^2/2$ otherwise.

So, the only region bounded by the three curves is the "triangle" whose "sides" are:

- $y=x^2$ from $(0,0)$ to $(2,4)$.
- $y=2x$ from $(2,4)$ to $(4,8)$.
- $y=x^2/2$ from $(0,0)$ to $(4,8)$.

That is, the region whose area we are to compute is:

$$\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: 0\le x<2,x^2/2<y<x^2\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: 2\le x\le4,x^2/2<y<2x\}$$

(Of course, by "triangle" I mean a closed, simple curve piecewise defined in three differentiable pieces, and these pieces are the "sides".)

*Remark*: I couldn't help "seeing" the graphs in my mind, so I could easily have missed something. Perhaps some expert in formal geometry can catch a gap in my answer. Perhaps Jordan's theorem or something like that is needed.